Long delay and Grey Screen in iOS App Video Calls with WebRTC
In my native iOS app, the screen remains grey with no video for up to 3 minutes when I receive a video call using the WebRTC library. The video call connects successfully, and when I receive a callback in the function: func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didAdd rtpReceiver: RTCRtpReceiver, streams mediaStreams: [RTCMediaStream]) I attach a remote renderer to the UI. Initially, I only see a grey screen without any video frames. It consistently takes a long time, up to 3-4 minutes, to receive actual streaming video. I suspect that my receiver is not receiving keyframes for some reason. Is there a way to request that WebRTC force the sender side to send a keyframe?
I know there are keyframe intervals in the HardwareVideoEncoderFactory class for Android that can be overridden, but I can't find anything similar for iOS. I discovered the following in video_encoder.cc: BSL_FLAG(uint32_t, key_frame_interval, 100, "Specify key frame interval of video encoder"); However, I'm unsure how to utilize this at a higher level in Swift. Perhaps my issue requires a different solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
